How to add Serilog logging to a SignalR client?
Currently my hub builder looks like this:
hub = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(Constants.HubsUrl + "/MainHub", options =>
    {
        options.Headers.Add(Constants.HeaderToken, token);
        options.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.AddDebug();
        logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Warning);
    })
    .WithAutomaticReconnect(new[] { 
        TimeSpan.Zero, 
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
    })
    .Build();

How can I add the Serilog provider to my logging?

If I remember correctly, you configure Serilog as usual:
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();

Then in ConfigureLogging you call the AddSerilog method from the Serilog.Extensions.Logging NuGet package:
logging.AddSerilog();

